# Selenium-rc window causes permission denied message in IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am testing with Selenium-rc 1.0.3 and I am getting a Permission denied error message in IE when I run my IDE script from the command line.

I am trying to run an IDE script in Internet explorer using the selenium control RC 1.0.3
from the command line:

> `java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlsuite "*iexploreproxy" "url
>   address/where" "C:\Users\sat\Documents\selenium\suite.html"
>   "C:\Users\sat\Documents\selenium scripts\results.htm" at this point`

The IE window pops up saying as below

I get a security warning saying "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?" I hit Yes and I see this error in the test runner window:

```
Webpage error details

Message: Access is denied.
Line: 177
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: xx.xx.xx.xxx/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-testrunner.js
```

UPDATE:

I looked at the line 177 and char :9 in the script and it points to

```
var runInterval = 0;

/** SeleniumFrame encapsulates an iframe element */
var SeleniumFrame = classCreate();
objectExtend(SeleniumFrame.prototype, {

    initialize : function(frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        addLoadListener(this.frame, fnBind(this._handleLoad, this));
    },

    getWindow : function() {
        return this.frame.contentWindow;
    },

    getDocument : function() {
        return this.frame.contentWindow.document; - line 177 char 9
    },

    _handleLoad: function() {
        this._attachStylesheet();
        this._onLoad();
        if (this.loadCallback) {
            this.loadCallback();
        }
```

Do you know what the error is about? Why do I get that? I see my test cases and everything in the test runner window, but I can't run them in the IE browser. I searched the web with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have much experience with running the test from CLI, but have you tried starting Selenium RC with administrator permission?

Any particular reason for not using the new Selenium 2 IWebDriver and a test framework?

The error might be caused by the use of iframe/frameset and IE's security settings. Default settings are that, if a site uses iframe/frameset and the frame content originates from 2 different root domains, then this is a security risk. Try is add the sites to your list thrusted site for IE. Have you tried to ude the firefox driver instead (will not have this security restriction).

Comment: No good reason actually, I just started using selenium RC so I thought it would be easier to to start with RC 1.X.X instead of 2.0

Comment: I already tried with the admin permission and deleting the cookies in the IE browser, but no avail. I updated my original post above with the code where is fails

Comment: we have only one root domain. i have no problems with the firefox browser. thanks for the pointers though. Appreciate it.